# Incompatible heap sizes error in Sonarqube

Tags: java, macos, sonarqube

I'm trying to install SonarQube on a Maxc (actually sonar source, tutorial is at http://chapter31.com/2013/05/02/installing-sonar-source-on-mac-osx/). The result of the "sonar start" command is the following output in sonar.log:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
JVM exited while loading the application.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I've tried to set the Java properties correctly in sonar.properties:

```
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xms512m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

The system is a Macbook Pro running OSX 10.11.1. Typing "java -version" into the command line outputs java version "1.6.0_65".

Comment: Which version are you trying to install? Latest SonarQube version require Java 7 or 8 I think.

Comment: It's sonar 5.2. The Java version is likely the problem, looks like.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. If you got the solution please post the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had java installed even then i was also getting the same error in my mac system and i just installed "Java SE Development Kit 8u60"(jdk-8u60-macosx-x64.dmg) for "Mac OS X x64" and then the issue got fixed.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html

so i think just installing "Java SE Development Kit 8u60" for right system from above link may fix this issue for others who ever faces this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it needs quotes?

```
sonar.web.javaOpts="-Xms512m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

I think it picking up the Xms, but ignoring the rest.  Meaning Xms is probably greater than default Xmx, which produces the error.