# JVM error in Sonarqube

Tags: java, macos, jvm, sonarqube

I am doing set up of Sonar Qube on my mac. I have started to install but stuck with an error.

I have referred another thread but it seems it is not resolved till now.
[Incompatible heap sizes error in Sonarqube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701426/incompatible-heap-sizes-error-in-sonarqube)

```
$ sh sonar.sh console
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 1    | Error occurred during initialization of VM
jvm 1    | Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
wrapper  | JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I am using mac OS X 10.11.2. I tried to setup `sonar.web.javaOpts` but with no success.  Typing "java -version" into the command line outputs java version "1.6.0_65".

Any help?

Comment: First of all, before proceeding here, update your Java to version 8. Version 6 is ancient, highly unsupported and it does not even get security fixes anymore. Then we can talk.

Comment: Moreover, which sonarqube version are you using ? LTS version of SonarQube (so the oldest version you should use) only supports java >= 7.

Comment: I have installed java 8.0 but it was showing me 6.0 version on terminal. After installing JDK it is showing me correct version of java on terminal also.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am a windows user and i don't know about Mac but this might give you a hint 
Just to add one variable in system variable 
Follow this

1.Right-click on This PC.

2. Go to Advanced system settings. One pop up window will open.
3. Click on Environment variables.
4. And then add

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS
```

```
-Xmx512M
```

this under the user variables.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by installing JDK from link [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)